# Generate random dates

Tags: ruby

I use this code to generate date in Ruby.

```
DateTime.strptime("10/26/2015 07:09:52 AM", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

How I can generate random date with range for example 6 months?

Comment: Do you need dates or datetimes?

Comment: Can you show me with both options?

Comment: I just wanted round numbers for mine :)

Comment: You should only use `DateTime` when dealing with historic dates (or historic versions of Rails). Otherwise, use `Time`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a much simpler way - if we assume say 15,552,000 seconds in 6 months for a round number (86400 * 180), then you can do:

```
Time.now - rand(15552000)
```

To subtract a random amount of seconds from the current time, and get a random Time object within the last 6 months.

You can then use [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to format it in whatever format you wish:

```
(Time.now - rand(15552000)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
=> "11/02/2016 12:04:05 AM"
```

This also doesn't depend on Rails for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Random datetime between now and six months into the future.

Doesn't suppose all months are 30 days:

```
now = DateTime.now
six_months_later = now >> 6

days_variance = (six_months_later - now).to_i

random_moment = now + Rational(rand(days_variance * 86400), 86400)

random_moment.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```